# Loading data in Angular Material Card

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Scenario :**

- I'm using ng2-charts to render charts in angular material cards.
- I've 8 cards, each cards should render its own data.

**Problem :**

- My issue is, Same `pieChartData` is getting displayed in all the cards.

  > Note: I could see it is overriding the previous `pieChartData`

**Code :**
Below function will be called 8 times on `ngonit`

```
    cardsData = [
      { title: 'Item 1', cols: 2, rows: 1, item: 'item1' },
      { title: 'Item 1', cols: 2, rows: 1, item: 'item2' },
      { title: 'Item 1', cols: 2, rows: 1, item: 'item3' }
...
  ];

  getItems(RapidViewID: string, SprintID: string) {
    this.httpSubscription = this.service.getIssues(RapidViewID, SprintID)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.pieChartData = [completedIssues, issuesNotCompleted];
      });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="300px">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cardsData" 
    [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-header class="bw-cp-dashboard-title">
        {{ card.title }}
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <div>
            <canvas *ngIf="pieChartData" baseChart 
      [data]="pieChartData" [labels]="pieChartLabels" 
      [chartType]="pieChartType"></canvas>
        </div>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: can you please create a small demo over stackblitz, so that we can see the code and will be able to answer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed using correctly `*ngFor` but then in your `<canvas>` field you are assigning each card the same data coming from the `getItems` service. You need to split this data and assign to correct `cardsData` data and then call in canvas using for example `card.completedIssues`.

Comment: But `card. completedIssues` does not exit in cardsData, so how do i suppose to do `card.completedIssues` it won;t work

Comment: you are supposed to create it yourself and assign to cardsData object so Angular can loop over it using map for example and assigning each object property to the cardsData.

Comment: `cardsData ` is static and `pieChartData ` is dynamic based on http response, so how do I push the `pieChartData` to `cardsData` ?

Comment: maybe in this case you want to do the opposite and loop over the dynamic data to which you'll push the cardsData? So create an empty object, dynamically on subscribe push the result from getItems service and the cardsData and then in the html template use that object for *ngFor